# Каково смысловое значение предлога "в качестве"?

Tags: пунктуация

В мои обязанности ***как работника Министерства*** входит заполнение бланков, выдача направления, учёт наличности свободных кабинетов и другие обязанности.

Может ли в данном случае ***как*** выступать в значении предлога  "в качестве"?

Answer (score 1):

*В мои обязанности **как работника Министерства** входит заполнение бланков, выдача направления, учёт наличности свободных кабинетов и другие обязанности.*

Здесь возможна прямая замена: в качестве  работника Министерства.

Слово ***качество*** известно с XI  века, производное от слов ***как***, какой. Заимствовано из старославянского языка, а там — калька с греческого.

**Из словаря**: В качестве кого-чего. **в зн. предлога**. В роли, на правах; в виде. Ему пришлось выступить в качестве переводчика. Использовать в качестве мебели.